# How to faster running speed of this query in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I'm now trying to pull some data from Hive tables and put them together in a new table. Steps are: pull transactionid with other infomation to one table; use transactionid to join with another table to get full url info.

I built the query which should work towards my needs, but it's running super slow. It ran over 30 mins without showing any result. (I need it to be done within 15 mins) Same query in Vertica should be able to finish within 5 mins. Need find some ways to faster the query.

-- separate related search urls to rows

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bi_etl.tblrelatedsearch;
CREATE TABLE bi_etl.tblrelatedsearch AS
select      eventdate
            ,coalesce(referringtransactionid, transactionid) as transactionid
            ,deviceguid
            ,platform
            ,storeid
            ,relatedurl
FROM        scribe.tblscriberelatedsearchresults LATERAL view explode (anchorurls) adTable as relatedurl
where       eventdate >= '2019-10-15'
and         storeid in (49,446,368,321,81,422,450,457)
;



-- with pagetype version
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bi_etl.tblrelatedsearchpg;
CREATE TABLE bi_etl.tblrelatedsearchpg as
select      a.eventdate
            ,a.transactionid
            ,a.platform
            ,a.storeid
            ,b.requesturl
            ,b.pagetype 
            ,a.relatedurl
            ,case when 
                a.url ilike '%keywork%' then 'Keyword'
                when
                a.url ilike '%sb0%' then 'SB'
                when
                a.url ilike '%sb1%' then 'SB'
                when
                a.url ilike '%sb2%' then 'SB'
                when
                a.url ilike '%sb3%' then 'SB'
                when
                a.url ilike '%ideas-and-advice%' then 'IDEAS & ADVICE'
                when
                a.url ilike '%top-rated%' then 'Top Rated'
                else   'ELSE' end
                as  relatedpagetype
from        bi_etl.tblrelatedsearchs a
left join   scribe.tblscribepagerequest b 
on          a.eventdate = b.eventdate
and         a.transactionid = b.transactionid
and         a.deviceguid = b.deviceguid
where       b.eventdate >= '2019-10-15'
and         b.storeid in (49,446,368,321,81,422,450,457)
;
```

Optimize query, make it faster in Hive.

Comment: Why are you using a `left join`, when the `WHERE` clause turns it back into an inner join?

Comment: What Gordon says. Change outer join to inner join, and add a filter on `a.eventdate`.

Comment: Just changed left join to inner join.. but it's still very slow, waited 30 mins without result coming out...

Comment: There are dbms where the implicit cast eventdate >= '2019-10-15' is very critical because it converts eventdate into char and then compares the contend. Cast this as date (eventdate >= date '2019-10-15') should work